# Rutherford Scattering and Impact Parameter

Tags: atomic-physics

In Modern Physics for Scientists and Engineers chapter 4 the question number 5 is giving me an issue. It states: Calculate the impact parameter for scattering a 7.7-MeV alpha particle from gold at an angle of (a) 1° and (b) 90°. I've deduced to use the impact parameter equation. I'm confused where it has Z_1 and Z_2. Are they charges, masses, or something else?

Comment: You would generally read the source where you found the equation to understand what the symbols in that equation mean. Of course there is the possibility that they were introduced pages (or even chapters) earlier, so if the source has a list of common symbols (which might go be some other name) you'll want to consult that rather than paging backward through the source scanning for the explanation (which is the other option).

Comment: It didn't list them. It is one of the few moments where the authors either forgot or assumed natural understanding. I've been looking over notes and trying but haven't found a clear answer. I don't need you to help with the actual question just two variables within. There is really no effort to show since I'm not sure what they even are? All I've been able to do is re-read over material to no avail. That is why I'm on here in the first place.

Comment: Z usually signifies the atomic number (number of protons). A signifies the mass number (number of protons+number of neutrons)